# Assume that $f(t)$ and $tf(t)$ are bounded. $F(s)=\mathcal{L}(f(t))(s)$, show that $\mathcal{L}(tf(t))(s)=-F'(s)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method, laplace-expansion

**Question :** Assume that $f(t)$ and $tf(t)$ are bounded.
Denoting $$F(s)=\mathcal{L}(f(t))(s)$$ show that $$\mathcal{L}(tf(t))(s)=-F'(s)$$

**My Try :** I know that
$$\mathcal{L}(f(t))(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t) \;dt$$

How to prove that Laplace Transform of $f(t)$ is equal to $-F'(s)$?
I'm not sure how to solve this problem, what I know is that the Laplace Transform of $f(t)$ is $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t) \;dt$

Comment: Of course you meant the Laplace transform of $t f(t)$. Click on edit to see the mathjax in [other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laplace-transform). The solution is to differentiate the integral representation of $F(s)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @reuns mentioned in his comment, 
‎$$\frac{d}{ds}F(s)=\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty e^{-st}y(t)dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{ds}e^{-st}y(t)dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}(-ty(t))dt={\cal L}(-tf)$$‎

Comment: Thanks! It really help me.

Comment: You're welcome!